# Not able to access service on minikube cluster| Istio

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices, minikube, istio

[Startup Logs of Pod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKOoX.png)  I am not able to access a spring boot service on my minikube cluster.
On my local machine,I configured minikube cluster and built the docker image of my service. My service contains some simple REST endpoints.

I configured minikube to take my local docker image or should I say pull my docker image. But now when I do

```
kubectl get services -n istio-system
```

I get the below services
[kubectl get services|Services list in minkube cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiBia.png) | 
[Kubectl get pods all namespaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxHwn.png) | [Kubectl describe service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96QUs.png)

I am trying to access my service through below command

`minikube service producer-service --url`

which gives http://192.168.99.100:30696

I have a ping URL in my service so ideally I should be getting response by hitting http://192.168.99.100:30696/ping

I am not getting any response here. Can you guys please let me know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you describe would suggest a port mapping problem. Is your Spring boot service on the default port of 8080? Does the internal port of your Service match the port the Spring boot app is running on (it'll be in your app startup logs). The port in your screenshot seems to be 8899. It's also possible your pod is in a different namespace from your service. It would be useful to include your app startup logs and the output of 'kubectl get pods --all-namespaces', and 'kubectl describe service producer-service'.

Comment: Hey @Ryan , My Spring Boot service is running on 8899. I have modified the default port in application.properties of the boot app so it runs on 8899. My Pod is in the same namespace as all istio services i.e. istio-system. I have attached the startup logs of the pod.

Comment: Could you try deploying a test app to the default namespace and exposing it via NodePort for comparison e.g. https://github.com/ryandawsonuk/minions/blob/master/README.md)? Checking if you can access that would help narrow down if the problem relates to your minikube port range, the namespace, the app or something else. If you have the yaml of your Service or the command used to create it that would also be useful.

Comment: Sure I will try out the above. Meanwhile , I have added all the screenshots. Can you please look into "kubectl describe services" and let me know if there is anything I am missing.

Comment: Thanks for adding that. I don't see any obvious cause. It seems like it should be exposed with NodePort in much the same way as the example. My best ideas at the moment are that the normal minikube port range isn't open or that something in the cluster blocks it (istio maybe).